# Python ARM in Docker - Installing requirements takes ages

Tags: python, docker, arm, gitlab-ci, github-actions

I want to run a Docker container with some Python bots inside. These scripts need libraries like pandas, numpy and matplotlib.
Everything works great in an x86 environment, but building the image on a Arm environment takes ages.
From what I understood, it seems like it needs to compile the libraries for Arm instead of just downloading the compiled files. I am trying to find a way to avoid all of this.

1. Matplotlib, pandas, numpy: They're pretty heavy packages, but I need just a few functionalities. Is the a slim version of these libraries?
2. Any way to store the compiled stuff in a permanent cache somewhere in the pipeline? (I am using both GitHub and GitLab to build this)

Any help is appreciated
Regards

Answer (score 1):

As @Itamar Turner-Trauring mentioned, `matplotlib`, `numpy`, `pandas` and many more libraries store wheels for `aarch64` as well as for `x86`.
In my case, `pip` was downloading the `x86` wheels by default, and then it must compile them during the build and it takes ages.

After changing the `pandas` version I was using from `1.1.5` to `1.3.5`, pip logs changed

**from:**

`Downloading https://****/pypi/download/pandas/1.1.5/pandas-1.1.5.tar.gz (5.2 MB)`

**To:**

`Downloading https://****/pypi/download/pandas/1.3.5/pandas-1.3.5-cp39-cp39-manylinux_2_17_aarch64.manylinux2014_aarch64.whl (10.9 MB)`

**And the entire build time changed from 58 to 8 minutes.**

Answer (score 0):

Matplotlib at least has ARM wheels (`aarch64`). The way I checked as going to https://pypi.org/project/matplotlib/, clicking on Download Files on the left, and looking for `aarch64` wheels.

So you should be able to get wheels if you're using a sufficiently new version of pip. Make sure you do `pip install --upgrade pip` before installing other packages.

Second, if you do need to compile from scratch, you can cache the resulting files using BuildKit's new caching features—see here https://pythonspeed.com/articles/docker-cache-pip-downloads/. You may need to specify a different directory to cache, wherever the temporary wheels end up, but it should be possible.

Comment: I am not an expert of python, but I think the docker builder is indeed downloading the wheel and then compiling it. It takes nearly 2 hrs tho to compile matplotlib, numpy and pandas and push the container